# grunt magento2 warning sign shows magento command

Tags: php, gruntjs, magento2

I got a problem using grunt

The warning sign is

```
jit-grunt: Plugin for the "&&" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "&&" failed. Used --force, continuing.

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "php" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "php" failed. Used --force, continuing.

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "bin/magento" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "bin/magento" failed. Used --force, continuing.

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "dev" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "dev:source-theme:deploy" failed. Used --force, continuing.

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "css/styles-m" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "css/styles-m" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

It's done but It doesn't convert less into css

When I take a look at combo.js file, the tasks above which is "&&", "php", "bin/magento" is there as a part of command

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grunt fails because it tries to execute two commands joined by double ampersand `&&`.

This is [a bug](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec/issues/79) that appears in `grunt-exec 2.0.0`. Upgrading to `3.0.0` didn't help me, but downgrading to `~1.0.0` fixed the problem.

Edit package.json so the line for grunt-exec reads:

```
"grunt-exec": "~1.0.0",
```

Then run `npm-update` to download the older version of the package. Grunt should work after that.